# Spatial cross correlation field of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I have 1000 observation stations over the US for which I need to get the cross-correlation matrix of size 1000x1000. I can do so by doing

```
[corelMat,pval] = corr([A1 A2 .... A1000],'type','kendall')
```

However, I want to put zero to those elements in the cross-correlation matrix where the p-value is less than 0.001.

How can I accomplish this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

Simply search for values in `pval` that are less than 0.001, then use this to index into `corelMat` and set those values to zero.  As such:

```
corelMat(pval < 0.001) = 0;
```

`pval < 0.001` generates a logical matrix where `true` denotes those p-values that are less than 0.001 and `false` otherwise.  By providing a logical matrix that is the same size as `corelMat` as an argument into `corelMat`, you are only changing the corresponding positions in `corelMat` that were `true` from `pval`.  Once you find these positions, you change those values in `corelMat` to 0.

---

Hope this helps!